# Taking a Parse Date, Converting to String and Display in Cell Detail

Tags: xcode, swift, date, parse-platform

I am trying to take the column createdAt from a Parse class, and to display this date in a cell detail label (Subtitle styled cell).

I am doing this the following way:

```
    if let createdDate: AnyObject = object["createdAt"] as? NSDate {

        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY"

        var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(createdDate as! NSDate)

        if dateString.isEmpty {

            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Undefined"

        } else {

            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = dateString

        }

    }
```

However, all I get is the word "Detail" below the Title label because at runtime it appears to evaluate the first `let createdDate: AnyObject`, but then skips the rest of the code, including the label assignment.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with getting the `createdAt` date. `createdAt` is a *special value* which is provided as `PFObject`'s property. So you should be reading it like this:

```
if let object = object as? PFObject {
    let createdDate = object.createdAt
}
```

Now this will give you an object of type `NSDate`.

Comment: Thank you! The following worked for me with your assistance:

`if let object = object {
            
            let createdDate = object.createdAt
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY"
            var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(createdDate!)
            if dateString.isEmpty {
                cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Undefined"
            } else {
                cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = dateString
            }`